# Move option color another location

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product

Hi How can I move color option another place in product cart file view.phtml. I found code

```
 <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
 <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
 <?php endif;?>
```

but this is generate option color together whit button add to cart I want split add to cart and color option.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these links and you will find your solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534432/magento-product-custom-options-to-be-positioned-below-the-price

http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/magento-configurable-product-type-part-1/

http://inchoo.net/magento/updating-options-of-configurable-product-that-is-already-in-the-cart/